# requests.get(url) return error code 404 from kubernetes api while the response could be get via curl/GET

Tags: python, httprequest, kubernetes

i met a problem by using requests.get() on kubernetes api

```
url = 'http://10.69.117.136:8080/api/v1/namespaces/"default"/pods/tas-core/'
json = requests.get(url)
print json.content
```

error code 404 will be returned as:
{"kind": "Status","apiVersion": "v1","metadata": {},"status": "Failure","message": "pods \"tas-core\" not found","reason": "NotFound","details": {"name": "tas-core","kind": "pods"},"code": 404}

but if i use GET/curl, the response could be returned successfully:

```
curl http://10.69.117.136:8080/api/v1/namespaces/"default"/pods/tas-core/
```

{"kind": "Pod","apiVersion": "v1","metadata": {"name": "tas-core","namespace":"default","selfLink": "/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/tas-core","uid": "a264ce8e-a956-11e5-8293-0050569761f2","resourceVersion": "158546","creationTimestamp": "2015-12-23T09:22:06Z","labels": {"app": "tas-core"},"annotations": {"ctrl": "dynamic","oam": "dynamic"}},"spec": {"volumes":[ ...

further more shorter url works fine

```
url = 'http://10.69.117.136:8080/api/v1/namespaces/'
json = requests.get(url)
print json.content
```

{"kind":"NamespaceList","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{"selfLink":"/api/v1/namespaces/","resourceVersion":"220452"},"items":[{"metadata":{"name":"default","selfLink":"/api/v1/namespaces/default","uid":"74f89440-a94a-11e5-9afd-0050569761f2","resourceVersion":"6","creationTimestamp":"2015-12-23T07:54:55Z"},"spec":{"finalizers":["kubernetes"]},"status":{"phase":"Active"}}]}

where did i wrong?

Comment: Try using a raw string `url = r'http://` <-- note the `r` in front

Comment: i tried, but raw string doesn't work :(. 
As the answer from Jan Vlcinsky, by deleting the quotes around "default" works :)
anyway thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making the request from `requests` and from command line sends it to different urls.

The `requests` request from Python code really tries to use url including the quotes.

`curl` from command line does strip the quotes (in other cases it escapes the quotes).

I am unable to test your real url for real requests, but I guess, that following might work:

```
url = 'http://10.69.117.136:8080/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/tas-core/'
json = requests.get(url)
print json.content
```

Comment: yes! you are right, the code are running now! the quotes are the trouble maker. Thanks.